# PHP Split query string into array with keys/values

Tags: php, jquery

I am passing the following query string into a PHP method

```
searchFilterKeyword=ff&searchFilterDateEntered=07%2F29%2F2019&searchFilterStatus=1&searchFilterQuarantineStatus=&searchFilterSize=&searchFilterKennel=&searchFilterType=
```

How would I `explode` this so that the following array is generated:

```
[
  'searchFilterKeyword' => 'ff',
  'searchFilterDateEntered' => '07%2F29%2F2019',
  'searchFilterStatus' => 1,
  'searchFilterQuarantineStatus' => '',
  'searchFilterSize' => '',
  'searchFilterKennel' => '',
  'searchFilterType' => ''
];
```

Also I would have to reformat the date to remove the `%2F`. I have to do all of this, because I can't pass in `new FormData()` object into a jquery call like

```
{
  'action': 'test',
  'type': 'test',
  'data': new FormData()
}
```

Comment: Your last statement about FormData doesn't seem relevant to the rest of the question. Also note that if that really is the issue then you would simply need to provide ***all*** the values in a FormData object using `append()`, eg. `formData.append('action', 'test')`

Comment: take a look at [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Answer (score 3):

To covert the query string into an array, you can use [`parse_str`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$string = 'searchFilterKeyword=ff&searchFilterDateEntered=07%2F29%2F2019&searchFilterStatus=1&searchFilterQuarantineStatus=&searchFilterSize=&searchFilterKennel=&searchFilterType=';
$output = [];
parse_str($string, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Where `$string` is your query string and `$output` is an empty array where the values are populated

Answer (score 2):

You can get it done with PHP's  `parse_str(string, array)` method.

> This method accepts two `parameters`. The first one is the string
>   which you want to parse, the other one is the array to store the
>   parsed string.

```
$arr = [];
$queryStr = 'searchFilterKeyword=ff&searchFilterDateEntered=07%2F29%2F2019&searchFilterStatus=1&searchFilterQuarantineStatus=&searchFilterSize=&searchFilterKennel=&searchFilterType=';
parse_str($queryStr, $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [searchFilterKeyword] => ff
    [searchFilterDateEntered] => 07/29/2019
    [searchFilterStatus] => 1
    [searchFilterQuarantineStatus] => 
    [searchFilterSize] => 
    [searchFilterKennel] => 
    [searchFilterType] => 
)
```